# How can I add a link on the "Structure" admin page?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I created a view page with the path being `/abc` and I want to add this link on Administrative page with a link in Drupal 8.

[image]

Comment: By "view page", do you mean it's created in views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to /admin/structure/menu/manage/admin and add this link.

Answer (score 2):

In a custom module, create a file called `mymodule.links.menu.yml`. Inside this file, add the following:

```
view.abc_links.page_1: #your view route
  title: 'ABC Link'
  route_name: view.abc_links.page_1 #your view route
  description: 'ABC Description'
mymodule.admin.structure.settings:
  title: 'API Link'
  description: 'ABC Description'
  route_name:  view.abc_links.page_1 #your view route
  parent: system.admin_structure
```

Comment: +1! And maybe OP changes the path of the view to /admin/abc to have this view rendered in the admin theme.